# libxml2 get offset into XML text of node

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I need to know at which offset into an xml string a specific arbitrary node somewhere in dom can be found after xmlReadMemory was used to get dom. The problem is I can't figure out where to get the xmlParserCtxtPtr from to pass as first argument to xmlParserFindNodeInfo because my entire process of parsing yields no such context; only a xmlDoc.

Comment: [It looks like](http://xmlsoft.org/library.html) xmlReadMemory is used with the "push" method, but you could use [xmlCreateMemoryParserCtxt](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parserInternals.html#xmlCreateMemoryParserCtxt) with the "pull" method, that would give you an xmlParserCtxtPtr .

Comment: The xmlCreateMemoryParserCtx does not appear to be available to me (CentOS 7 default libxml2). There is a xmlCreateDocParserCtx and I've changed the parsing to use this together with xmlCtxtReadDoc and then use the context with xmlParserFindNodeInfo  and the node but the result is always NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me (libxml2 documentation leaves little to desire, had to download source code and dig in the lib until I understood enough to hack this together). The key is:

```
xmlSetFeature(ctxt, "gather line info", (void *)&v);
```

Here is some code to illustrate:

```
const char *xml = ...
xmlParserCtxt *ctxt = NULL;
xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
if (!(ctxt = xmlCreateDocParserCtxt((const unsigned char *)xml)))
    return -1;
int v = 1;
xmlSetFeature(ctxt, "gather line info", (void *)&v);
if (xmlParseDocument(ctxt) == -1)
{
    xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt);
    return -1;
}
else
{
    if ((ctxt->wellFormed) || ctxt->recovery)
        doc = ctxt->myDoc;
    else
    {
        xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt);
        return -1;
    }
}

// use doc to get a node and then xmlParserFindNodeInfo(ctxt, node)
…

xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt);
```